# php : why this incorrect way of requesting databases is not vulnerable

Tags: php, sql-injection

I have this particular code (this is a mwe) and I can't understand why there is not MySQL Error getting printed in browser or apache logs files :

```
$sql= "SELECT * from vulnDB where username = admin and password = '" . $_POST['password'] ."'";

if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
   $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
   if ($_POST['password'] == $row['password']) {
     echo "Welcome!";
   } else {
     echo "This password is incorrect";
   }   
} else {
   echo "Error";
}
```

When I enter legitimate values, the code is correctly executed (`Welcome` or `This password is incorrect`), when I enter `"` or `'`, I reach the `Error` clause but nothing is getting printed and this code seems to be immune to SQLi.

Is there some particular protection in PHP to avoid anyway SQLi injection to success?
Appropriate protection would consist on using PDO, but I have found this code which obviously seems to be vulnerable; and can't trigger sqli error syntax or other thinks out of it, only "error" gets printed.

Comment: putting it in a try catch should return any errors you are not specifically checking for. at the very least, your code should echo the `Error` string

Comment: You don't check for errors, so you just can't see them. checkout [mysqli_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php). Mysqli layer won't raise a php exception.

Comment: @khuderm OP stated: "_only "error" gets printed_"

Comment: Have you tried actually passing in a sql command instead of just a `'`? Try passing something like `'; DROP TABLE vulnDB`

Comment: @jfadich won't work, because mysqli_query only allows _one_ statement. (in contrast to mysqli_multi_query)

Comment: "*Appropriate protection would consist on using PDO*", no, appropriate protection would consist of using **prepared statements**, you can do that using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) *or* [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To inject SQL in a useful way, you need to make the SQL statement valid *with your parameter injected into the string*. Simply injecting `'` won't turn into valid SQL. (It would result in something like `SELECT * from vulnDB where username = admin and password = '''`.)

You'd need to inject something like `' OR password IS NOT NULL AND '' = '` (note: I haven't tested this) to create a working attack.

When you don't use prepared statements, and you print a string from user input directly into SQL that gets executed, **you are vulnerable to SQL injection.**